# qiskit with our own backend

Tags: qiskit, hardware

In our laboratory we have our own cryostat and quantum chips, so I wondered if is it even possible to mate our own hardware (HDAWG, etc.) with qiskit framework? It would be great to build pulse schedules for calibrations and measurements with such a great tool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can! You need to implement a `Backend` interface. Here some details https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/providers.html#id2